Why can't tikzexternalize write to a directory above
I use the command
\tikzexternalize[prefix=../figures-tikz/]

and I got the error message
! I can't write on file `../figures-tikz/BQ-m-meca_0.md5'.
If on the other hand I write the command
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures-tikz/]

no problem.
how to force tikzexternalize to write to the "../figures-tikz/" directory?
I compile with Xelatex and Shell-escape

Note that providing a minimal example fo others to use makes it a lot easier to help

Can you create a link (shortcut) in the file system so that it thinks the subdirectory of the parent is actualyl a subdirectory of the currentt (or viice verses)?

The default security policy for texlive (set in texmf.cnf) is
% Do we allow TeX \input or \openin (openin_any), or \openout
% (openout_any) on filenames starting with `.' (e.g., .rhosts) or
% outside the current tree (e.g., /etc/passwd)?
% a (any)        : any file can be opened.
% r (restricted) : disallow opening dot files
% p (paranoid)   : as `r' and disallow going to parent directories, and
%                  restrict absolute paths to be under $TEXMFOUTPUT.
openin_any = a
openout_any = p


So you can not open files in parent directories for writing.
You could change that or simpler start tex in the parent directory.

Can this be allowed occasionally with a compilation directive (I use TexWorks)?
Otherwise how to launch (with Texworks) a compilation from the parent directory?

you can use xelatex --cnf-line="openout_any=a"  in texlive, no idea about miktex (or texworks) sorry
